# Unusual error message - sql server the row object is inconsistent. please rerun the query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm reviewing the error logs for an instance of SQL Server 2012 and found the following error in the log (error 669):

```
The row object is inconsistent. please rerun the query
```

I googled and the only answers seem to be generic listings of sys.messages showing the error number and error description.

Has anyone come across this error before? My thoughts so far is it indicates some kind of data corruption, but the error message doesn't say which database is affected.

Comment: Add you query to the question. And you can try to run a DBCC CHECKTABLE or DBCC CHECKDB

Comment: @Kri presumably they don't know the query if they just found this message in the logs and don't even know the database.

Comment: That's correct, I don't know what query as the message is in the error log. I just found if I click the 'details' tab of the error message, it shows the name of the relevant database in the hex dump. I just ran a DBCC CHECKDB('name') of the DB and it checked out OK.

Comment: I'm going to make a bet... I *bet* that the query in reference is using NOLOCK. Can you check this? If so, that's normal and if you want it to stop, stop using NOLOCK.

Comment: There is no query in reference, the message was in the error log (see the second and third comments above). It turns out the SQL Server Service was re-started today as it had become non-responsive. This error message occurred before the re-start and was mixed with other errors regarding memory pressure, so my guess is it's a follow-on error fom a low memory condition.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, I'd suggest running `DBCC CHECKDB` against all databases on that instance.  Here's a quick script that will run against each database (including system databases).  This could take quite a bit of time (depending on the size of your databases), but you need to let it finish running.

```
DECLARE @Message VARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @databaseList AS CURSOR;
DECLARE @databaseName AS NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @tsql AS NVARCHAR(500); 

SET @databaseList = CURSOR  LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY 
FOR
        SELECT QUOTENAME([name])
        FROM sys.databases
        WHERE [state] = 0;
OPEN @databaseList;
FETCH NEXT FROM @databaseList into @databaseName;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Message = 'Starting DBCC for ' + @databaseName + ' -> (' + convert(varchar,getdate(),121) + ')'
    RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    SET @tsql = N'DBCC CheckDB(' + @databaseName + ') WITH ALL_ERRORMSGS,NO_INFOMSGS;';
    RAISERROR(@tsql,0,1) WITH NOWAIT
    exec SP_EXECUTESQL @tsql;
    SET @Message = 'Completed DBCC for ' + @databaseName + ' -> (' + convert(varchar,getdate(),121) + ')'
    RAISERROR(@Message,0,1) WITH NOWAIT

    FETCH NEXT FROM @databaseList into @databaseName;
END
CLOSE @databaseList;
DEALLOCATE @databaseList;
```

Comment: Checkdb was OK for the database which I believe experienced the issue (see the earlier comment I added to the question). I'm reluctant to run checkdb now on the other DBs as the server is live, however there's a nightly maintenance plan to do this.

Comment: @Ubercoder - Ok, as I said, it was a 'first-step'.  You might look into setting up a [Server-Side Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx) trace to capture this event.  The 'time' that it occurs may also lead you to finding the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, used DBCC to Check the tables concerned and nothing was reported.

In the end we had to rebuild the indexes on 1 of the tables to rectify the problem.

Gary

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be because the subquery is returning duplicate records.

For example: in the below sub query if the `Employee` table has duplicate `ID`s then this issue can happen

```
DELETE 
FROM   employee
WHERE  id IN (SELECT TOP 1 id
              FROM   Employee
              WHERE  NAME IN (SELECT NAME
                              FROM   employee
                              GROUP BY
                                     NAME
                              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1))
```